# Wordpress consulta categoria e tag

Tags: php, wordpress

**Como busco os posts por categoria e por tag?**
Fiz assim e não deu certo:

```
query_posts(array( 
    'post_type' => 'noticias',
    'showposts' => 2,
    'category__and' => array(70),
    'tag__in'   => array(77),
) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi certo, vc está querendo pegar todos os posts de categoria específica de um Custom Post Type, certo ? category__and é usado para categoria do post padrão do wordpress. Em CPT para vc agrupar post por categorias vc utiliza taxonomia e para consultar utilize o parametro 'tax_query'.

Tente dessa forma:

```
query_posts(array( 'post_type' => 'noticias',
   'posts_per_page' => 2,
   'tax_query' => array( array(
   'taxonomy' => 'ID_DA_TAXYNOMIA', 
   'field' => 'term_id', 
   'terms' => array( 70 ) ))));
```